# python, using logistic regression to see which variable is adding more weight towards a positive prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels

so i have a banking data set, where i have to predict if customer would take a term deposit or not.
i have a column called job; which is categorical and has the job types of each customer.
i am currently in the EDA process and want to make out which job category contributes the most towards a positive prediction.

i intend to do this with logistic regression (not sure if this is right, alternative method sugestions are welcome).

so here is what i did;

i did one k- hot encoding for each job category(and have 1-0 values for each job type), and the target i
Did k-1 one hot, and have 1-0 values for Target_yes(1 = the customer accepted the term deposit and 0 the customer did not accept).

```
    job_management  job_technician  job_entrepreneur    job_blue-collar     job_unknown     job_retired     job_admin.  job_services    job_self-employed   job_unemployed  job_housemaid   job_student
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
45206   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
45207   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
45208   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
45209   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
45210   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

45211 rows × 12 columns
```

The target column looks like this;

```
0        0
1        0
2        0
3        0
4        0
        ..
45206    1
45207    1
45208    1
45209    0
45210    0
Name: Target_yes, Length: 45211, dtype: int32
```

I fit this to a sklearn logistic regression model and got the coefficients. Unable to interpret them, i looked for an alternative and came across stat model version. did the same with the logit function. In the example i saw online, he had used sm.get_constants for the x variable.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
model.fit(vari,tgt)
model.score(vari,tgt)
df = pd.DataFrame(model.coef_)
df['inter'] = model.intercept_
print(df)
```

The model score and print()df results are as follows:

```
0.8830151954170445(model score)

print(df)
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0 -0.040404 -0.289274 -0.604957 -0.748797 -0.206201  0.573717 -0.177778   

          7         8         9        10        11     inter  
0 -0.530802 -0.210549  0.099326 -0.539109  0.879504 -1.795323
```

When i use sm.get_constats, i get coefficients similar to the sklearn logisticRegression, but the Zscores, (which i intended to use to find the job type which contributes the most towards a positive prediction) becomes nan.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
logit = sm.Logit(tgt, sm.add_constant(vari)).fit()
logit.summary2()
```

Results are:

```
E:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:2495: FutureWarning:

Method .ptp is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use numpy.ptp instead.

E:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:1286: RuntimeWarning:

invalid value encountered in sqrt

E:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:901: RuntimeWarning:

invalid value encountered in greater

E:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:901: RuntimeWarning:

invalid value encountered in less

E:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py:1892: RuntimeWarning:

invalid value encountered in less_equal

Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.352610
         Iterations 13

Model:  Logit   Pseudo R-squared:   0.023
Dependent Variable:     Target_yes  AIC:    31907.6785
Date:   2019-11-18 10:17    BIC:    32012.3076
No. Observations:   45211   Log-Likelihood:     -15942.
Df Model:   11  LL-Null:    -16315.
Df Residuals:   45199   LLR p-value:    3.9218e-153
Converged:  1.0000  Scale:  1.0000
No. Iterations:     13.0000         
                  Coef.     Std.Err.    z   P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
const            -1.7968    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_management   -0.0390    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_technician   -0.2882    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_entrepreneur -0.6092    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_blue-collar  -0.7484    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_unknown      -0.2142    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_retired       0.5766    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_admin.       -0.1766    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_services     -0.5312    nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_self-employed   -0.2106     nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_unemployed  0.1011  nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_housemaid   -0.5427     nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
job_student     0.8857  nan     nan     nan     nan     nan
```

if i use the Stat models logit without the sm.get_constats, i get coefficients that are very different from the sklearn Logistic regression, but i get values for the zscore (which are all negative)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
logit = sm.Logit(tgt, vari).fit()
logit.summary2()
```

results are:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.352610
         Iterations 6

Model:  Logit   Pseudo R-squared:   0.023
Dependent Variable:     Target_yes  AIC:    31907.6785
Date:   2019-11-18 10:18    BIC:    32012.3076
No. Observations:   45211   Log-Likelihood:     -15942.
Df Model:   11  LL-Null:    -16315.
Df Residuals:   45199   LLR p-value:    3.9218e-153
Converged:  1.0000  Scale:  1.0000
No. Iterations:     6.0000      
                  Coef.     Std.Err.    z        P>|z|  [0.025  0.975]
job_management  -1.8357     0.0299  -61.4917    0.0000  -1.8943     -1.7772
job_technician  -2.0849     0.0366  -56.9885    0.0000  -2.1566     -2.0132
job_entrepreneur -2.4060    0.0941  -25.5563    0.0000  -2.5905     -2.2215
job_blue-collar  -2.5452    0.0390  -65.2134    0.0000  -2.6217     -2.4687
job_unknown      -2.0110    0.1826  -11.0120    0.0000  -2.3689     -1.6531
job_retired      -1.2201    0.0501  -24.3534    0.0000  -1.3183     -1.1219
job_admin.       -1.9734    0.0425  -46.4478    0.0000  -2.0566     -1.8901
job_services     -2.3280    0.0545  -42.6871    0.0000  -2.4349     -2.2211
job_self-employed-2.0074    0.0779  -25.7739    0.0000  -2.1600     -1.8547
job_unemployed   -1.6957    0.0765  -22.1538    0.0000  -1.8457     -1.5457
job_housemaid    -2.3395    0.1003  -23.3270    0.0000  -2.5361     -2.1429
job_student      -0.9111    0.0722  -12.6195    0.0000  -1.0526     -0.7696
```

Which of the two is better?
or should i use a completly different approach ?

Comment: My guess is that you have a singular design matrix when you add the constant because of the dummy variable trap.

Comment: will surely look into what that is and how i can do it  ! thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I fit this to a sklearn logistic regression model and got the
>   coefficients. Unable to interpret them, i looked for an alternative
>   and came across stat model version.

```
print(df)
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6  \
0 -0.040404 -0.289274 -0.604957 -0.748797 -0.206201  0.573717 -0.177778   

          7         8         9        10        11     inter  
0 -0.530802 -0.210549  0.099326 -0.539109  0.879504 -1.795323
```

The interpreation works like this:
Exponentiating the log odds gives you the odds ratio for a one-unit increase in your variable. So for example, if Target_yes(1 = the customer accepted the term deposit and 0 the customer did not accept) = 1 and a logistic regression coefficient of 0.573717, then you can assert that the odds of your outcome for "accept" are exp(0.573717) = 1.7748519304802 times that of the odds of your outcome in "no accept".

Comment: Thank you so very much for clarifying that for me! So the odds of accepting are 1.77485 times  of not accepting. In what order are these coefficients, are they the same as the input variables?? what does exp of negative coefficients give ?exp(-0.539109)  = 0.5832677124519539 is this the odds of not aceepting ?

Comment: negativ is still the same interpretation as positiv

Comment: Thank you so very much for taking the time to explain this to me ! thanks a lot !